# Do data sent with WebSockets or WebRTC needs CRC?

Tags: javascript, websocket, network-programming, webrtc, crc

I've read somewhere that when you sent data over plain UDP, then using cyclic redundancy check is a must to detect if the data isn't corrupted upon receival.

Is that also required for WebSockets and WebRTC, or web browsers do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use plain UDP with WebRTC:

- WebSockets works over TCP. Looking into [RFC 793, page 16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-16), is has a checksum. Thus, it is safe.
- WebRTC Data Channels work over SCTP over UDP. Looking into [RFC 4960, page 90](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#page-90) for SCTP:

> When sending an SCTP packet, the endpoint MUST strengthen the data
> integrity of the transmission by including the CRC32c checksum value
> calculated on the packet, as described below.

This means, all packets send over an RTCDataChannel do already have a CRC and all packets which arrive at the destination are not corrupted.
Thus, it is safe as well.

Keep in mind:

- `reliable: true`: Packet loss is detected and handled (restransmission)
- `reliable: false`: Packet loss is not detected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :) "Save"? Did you mean "safe"? And what about unreliable data channels? Do they need manual CRC?

Comment: Yes, I mean safe (corrected it). I guess, you do not need any additional CRC, since SCTP handles it (I updated my answer)